# Docker nginx & fpm: For some reason when I visit the mapped port it redirects into port 80

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am making this [wordpress solution](https://github.com/ellakcy/wordpress-with-plugins/tree/dev) and for "dieting" reasons I am moving into alpine-based images therefore I try to create a docker wordpress image based on `wordpress:php7.0-fpm-alpine` image.

On this I managed to use an external configuration ([file](https://github.com/ellakcy/wordpress-with-plugins/blob/dev/conf/nginx/wordpress_nginx.conf)) and via volume I pass it into nginx.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ .php{
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors  on;
  }
}
```

But when I try to visit it on a browser by giving http://localhost:8080 (where I map the port 80 it into my [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/ellakcy/wordpress-with-plugins/blob/dev/docker-compose.yml)):

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - './conf/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro'
    links:
      - "wordpress"
    volumes_from:
      - "wordpress:ro"

  wordpress-db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "wordpress"
      MYSQL_USER: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_USER}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'

  wordpress:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: ellakcy/wordpressswithplugins:alpine
    links:
      - wordpress-db
    environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wordpress-db:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_USER}'
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
        WORDPRESS_ADMIN_USERNAME: '${WORDPRESS_ADMIN_USER}'
        WORDPRESS_ADMIN_PASSWORD: '${WORDPRESS_ADMIN_PASSWORD}'
        WORDPRESS_URL: '${WORDPRESS_URL}'
```

But for some reason seems that redirects to port 80.

Also when I run via `docker-compose up` command I get the following piece of log:

```
wordpress_1     | 172.23.0.4 -  18/Aug/2017:12:36:57 +0000 "GET /index.php" 301
nginx_1         | 172.23.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2017:12:36:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.23.0.4 -  18/Aug/2017:12:41:22 +0000 "GET /index.php" 301
nginx_1         | 172.23.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2017:12:41:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0" "-"
```

So I guess for some reason the nginx performs a 301 redirect to port 80. Do you have any Idea why that happens?

## Edit 1

I also tried to set the 8080 port into the nginx configuration too:

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ .php{
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors  on;
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
    services:
      nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
          - './conf/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro'
        links:
          - "wordpress"
        volumes_from:
          - "wordpress:ro"

      wordpress-db:
        image: mariadb
        environment:
          MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
          MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD: "yes"
          MYSQL_DATABASE: "wordpress"
          MYSQL_USER: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_USER}'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'

      wordpress:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: ellakcy/wordpressswithplugins:alpine
        links:
          - wordpress-db
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wordpress-db:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_USER}'
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
            WORDPRESS_ADMIN_USERNAME: '${WORDPRESS_ADMIN_USER}'
            WORDPRESS_ADMIN_PASSWORD: '${WORDPRESS_ADMIN_PASSWORD}'
            WORDPRESS_URL: '${WORDPRESS_URL}'
```

I still get the same behaviour.

## Edit 2

I also tried to use the following nginx settings (fot the nginx container)

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
  }

  location ~ .php {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors  on;
  }

}
```

And still I see no light in my path.

## Edit 4:

Furtermore I tried to put the following content into the script [*wp_post_entrypoint.sh*](https://github.com/ellakcy/wordpress-with-plugins/blob/dev/wp_post_entrypoint.sh):

```
sed -i "define('WP_HOME', '${WORDPRESS_PATH}'); define('WP_SITEURL','$WORDPRESS_PATH');" ${WORDPRESS_PATH}/wp-config.php
```

In order to redirect correctly the wordpress. But still no light in my path.

### Edit 5:

I also made a [apache variant](https://github.com/ellakcy/wordpress-with-plugins/blob/dev/Dockerfile_apache) and I get the same behavior. I wonder if `wp-cli` somehow messes with installation.

Furthermore in apache variant when I provide with container's internal ip then the site gets served with the assets broken as expected.

### Edit 6:

I also whiped a plain one WITHOUT the custom wordpress image and it worked like a charm without 301 redirects that the custom one I am making behaves. Also plees keep in mind that the apache one is based on the `wordpress:php7.0-apache` one:

```
version: '2'
services:
#Wordpress
  wordpress-db:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
     - './data/wordpress/db:/var/lib/mysql'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_USER}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:php7.0-apache
    volumes:
      - './data/wordpress/www:/var/www/html'
    ports:
      - '8085:80'
    links:
      - wordpress-db
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wordpress-db:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_USER}'
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: '${WORDPRESS_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
```

Comment: Which wordpress image are you inheriting from?

Comment: I inherit from `wordpress:php7.0-fpm-alpine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that on when you perform an installation via `wp-cli` you pass the site's url WITHOUT ant `http://`, `"` and `'`. To ensure that please run:

```
WORDPRESS_URL=$(php -r "echo preg_replace('#^http?://|\"|\'#', '', rtrim('${WORDPRESS_URL}','/'));")
```

Before performing: `wp-cli core install` or in your case `wp ^params^ core install`

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on WordPress itself. Since you are reaching it on port 80 (from WordPress point of view, the external URL is on port 80, the nginx port), the site_url is probably mapped on port 80 and that causes the redirect.

First, try to map port 80 on your host with port 80 in the container to check if it works. If it does, you only need to make the site_url option of wordpress with the external URL you are actually using to reach it.

What's in the WORDPRESS_URL ENV var?

Comment: In worddpress WORDPRESS_URL is the setting that we tell into wordpress installation that this is the site url. Is what you gice on a gui installation when wordpress asks for the url of the site. In other words the enviromental variable is the site_url

Comment: And what did you put in the instance that is not working?

Comment: Mapping to 80 worked but I did not change a except port mapping and as expected the assets are breaking.

Comment: Can you check on the admin interface if the site URL is correct? Just as a double check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152293/discussion-between-dimitrios-desyllas-and-whites11).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with almost same nginx config

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root /srv/api/public;

        location / {
            index index.html;
        }

        location /api {
            try_files $uri /api.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is gone after I placed `index` directive into `/api` location block

```
    location /api {
        index api.php;
        try_files $uri /api.php?$query_string;
    }
```